# check if true fails. Return true but doesn't evaluate

Tags: php

I have a function that check if a user has a specific functionality enabled in his role.

```
function uar($role,$func,$pdo){
    $id = '';
    $id = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM ruolo_funzione WHERE ruolo='$role' AND funzione='$func'")->fetchColumn();
    if($id!=''){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I run the query directly it returns an $id so the function returns true.
In the menu page I check if it returns true or false:

```
<?php if(uar($_SESSION['ruolo'],38,$pdo)){?>
    <li class="subitem1">
    <a href="index.php?area=soff&sub=home">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

but it doesn't display anything. What is wrong with my code? what do I miss to get it working?

EDIT:
from mysql log one of the queries is:

```
SELECT id FROM ruolo_funzione WHERE ruolo='5' AND funzione='38'
```

that returns an id (checked) but doesn't evaluate to true

Comment: Where do `$role` and `$func` come from? Does the user provide these or are they hard-coded?

Comment: Have you tried `if($id){` instead of `if($id!=''){`

Comment: if `$_SESSION['ruolo']` is not assigned, you'll get an error, and the function won't be called. Make sure to enable error reporting and gain access to the PHP error log, otherwise you'll be in the dark with every error you get.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($id)` to see what you really got back?

Comment: $role comes from the db when the user logs in. $func is a code different for each function and is hardcoded.

Comment: @GolezTrol: uh, the function would still be called. php would simply issue an undefined index warning, and pass a php `null` in as the function argument, which then becomes `WHERE ruolo=''` in the query string.

Comment: $_SESSION['ruolo'] returns the expected value (echoed).

Comment: 1) If `$role` and `$func` come from the user, even if earlier in the session, don't just stick them in the SQL. Use a parameterized query. 2) What happens if you get 0 columns back? `FetchColumn` will return `false` and `false == ''` in PHP. 3) Try printing the contents of $id to see what you got back...

Comment: no user input for any of them. So no need to sanitize the input. What do you mean with "zero column"? The column exists, maybe the value doesn't (and this means reutrn false)

Comment: You still didn't do what @MarcB said. What is the output of `var_dump($id)`?

Comment: @Mike it returns the id. Guess what? restarted the web server and it came back to proper execution

Comment: @LelioFaieta That makes no sense...

Comment: @mike the mysql server hanged up. I restarted the server while adding var_dump and it fixed. I have some problems between php and mysql on this dev server (not my server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### From PDO Documentation

> #### `public mixed PDOStatement::fetchColumn ([ int $column_number = 0 ] )`
>
> Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.
>
> ### Nota:
>
> PDOStatement::fetchColumn() should not be used to retrieve boolean columns, as > it is impossible to distinguish a value of FALSE from there being no more rows > to retrieve. Use PDOStatement::fetch() instead.

As it, if your query returns no rows, it's going to return false,

So when you do
`if ($id!='')`

You're getting unexpected results as `false != ''` returns false, not true.

You should then test for false values not *falsy* values...

`$id !== false`

Remember, always use the three equal comparator `===` or `!==` to prevent these unexpected results.

### UPDATE:

Also, your query must have something wrong, as it is not returning any values. At least, it should be showing the functionality for at least the ones you have in your database.

### UPDATE2:

Verify your $_SESSION variable if it's beign populated correctly.

Also, check if your PDO query is working as expeceted.

Try `$pdo->errorInfo();`to check for any connection errors or something.

Comment: this doesn't change a bit the issue. The query is fine (see my edit)